# Error in JSP project : Impossible to load [], this classloader had already been stopped

Tags: java, jsp, classloader, java-ee-7, illegalstateexception

Since I begin a JSP project, I often have this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Impossible to load [], this classloader had already been stopped...
```

Can someone understand what it means ?

Thank you very much

Comment: can you provide more information on how are you getting this error

Comment: May be it is when I'm debugging...